# when I call a resource show function with an id the retruned page work without the style, NO css + js !! laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-9

Note: all other pages work fine!!, Except when I call from this function...

action in HTML

```
<a class="dropdown-item" style="border-right: 5px solid #00ff55;"  href="{{route('room.show',1)}}" >
تقييمات الغرف
</a>
```

Route in web.php

```
Route::resource('room', DailyTaskroomController::class);
```

The show function in the controller

```
public function show(DailyTaskroom $dailyTaskroom)
{
        $leader = DailyTaskroom::all()->last()->paginate(5);
        return view('tasks.room_view')->with('leader',$leader);
}
```

And this is the URL that appears in the URL bar.
-> http://127.0.0.1:8000/room/1

[This is the wanted page that appears without style!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAAP1.png)

Comment: Show complete controller function with params too

Comment: public function show(DailyTaskroom $dailyTaskroom)
    {
        $leader = DailyTaskroom::all()->last()->paginate(5);
        return view('tasks.room_view')->with('leader',$leader);
    }

Comment: developer tools is your best friend here. Maybe u have css linked in another file and mispelled it. Anyway, this is not enough data so that we can figure out your issue.
If u don't see it post whole blade file with related files

Comment: if you have no css/js it's  probably because the path is wrong. Use the inspector in your browser to check it first.